# Axios PUT doesn't update data

Tags: node.js, rest, express, vue.js, axios

I have this `VueJS` application that is using `Axios` to `PUT` an object to the server. The goal is to update this object in the database. The object already exists in the database but the object that is sent back with the `PUT` has some changed data. These changes are what I want to update to the database. The application runs without error messages but the data in the database is never updated.

> Client side

```
onUpload(): void {
    this.chosenRoute.name = this.routeName;
    this.chosenRoute.text.paragraphs[0] = this.routeDescription;
    this.chosenRoute.text.preamble = this.preamble;
    if(this.activity != "") this.chosenRoute.activity = this.activity;

    axios.put('http://localhost:8080/route/' + this.selectedRoute, JSON.stringify(this.chosenRoute), {
      onUploadProgress: uploadEvent => {
        console.log('Upload Progress' + Math.round(uploadEvent.loaded / uploadEvent.total) * 100 + " %");
      }
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

> Server side

```
app.put('/route/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    const routeId = req.params.id;
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    Route.update({'_id':routeId}, req.body, function(result) {
        return res.send(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no errors in your browser console? Do you have something in place to handle the pre-flight OPTIONS request this would generate? How about adding some debugging to your server-side script so you can see what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you shouldn't use `JSON.stringify` so your code should look like:

```
axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/route/${this.selectedRoute}`, this.chosenRoute, {
  onUploadProgress: uploadEvent => {
    console.log('Upload Progress' + Math.round(uploadEvent.loaded / uploadEvent.total) * 100 + " %");
  }
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Hope it will help you !

Comment: probably, because your express app have an limit. If you use express you should add `app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '1mb'}));`